# How to redirect a slash url to non slash url using htaccees

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My url looks like

```
 localhost/test/page1.php
```

I would like to hide the php extension so i have used the below method to hide the php extension

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now the url is

```
localhost/test/page1
```

But when i use the url like localhost/test/page1/ then it shows an error. HOw to redirect the slash url to non slash url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @user2569919: see online demo: `http://hostfrosh.org/test/test` and `http://hostfrosh.org/test/test/`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Rewrite Rule as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove slashes from incoming URI's that end with slashes.
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect redirect requests to PHP controllers
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

This will redirect any requests not to web root that end in slash a slash-cleansed URL with a HTTP 301 header.

Comment: Your code doesnt work fine.It shows an pagenot found.So i have used only RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] , when i use with slash in url it going back to test folder. not to page1